# salesforce1 app tab and view pages

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I am having 2 different environments for normal desktop salesforce application and salesforce1 app.

I am developing a salesforce1 mobile app. Both tab and view pages are different for normal desktop application and salesforce1 app. I am having a custom object i had created tab and view pages for salesforce1 app. I had added visualforce tab and view pages to salesforce1 menu. But i 1st added tab page which is working fine. But if i click on tab page it is redirecting to desktop view/detail page. But it want to redirect to normal mobile view page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your page is enabled for Salesforce1 access as shown below

[image]

Also, you haven't specified how you are navigating to your custom object, but this is how you can do it.

```
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
    // Salesforce1 navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
```